# Windows\System32\drivers\etc and GetDirectories

Tags: c#, io, directory

Does anyone know what's so special about 'etc' in terms of directory enumeration, are there others like it and how to get around it being invisible?

```
public class Foo
{
    [Test]
    public void Etc()
    {
        var etc = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc");
        Assert.True(etc.Exists);

        /* Expected: not <empty> But was:  <empty> */
        Assert.IsNotEmpty(etc.Parent.GetDirectories(etc.Name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you hit that folder in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Does the Assert return true if you run the code as Administrator? Or if you've changed your Folder Options to 'show hidden files'?

Comment: @Michael Yes, Explorer shows it, even File Open dialogs autocomplete it, as well as console's tab autocomplete.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I have show hidden & system files enabled, no UAC. Tried running it as a console app launched as admin, the .Length is still 0.

Comment: I was just about to say 'well etc is where the hosts file is' so perhaps it's inbuilt MS security. But have just read Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer so think that far more likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running your code on a 64-bit machine as a 32-bit process. And you're seeing the effects of the [file system redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

`C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc` is *not* redirected (it's documented as being exempt from redirection), and so is `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc` for both a 32-bit or 64-bit process.

But when you step up to `C:\windows\system32\drivers`, you're redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWow64\drivers` if you're running in a 32-bit process. And that directory doesn't have an `etc` directory under it.

Comment: And BOOM goes the dynamite! I was just on that same path, thanks for validating I was at least right about my beliefs!

Comment: Spot on, thanks! Is there a way to get "true" path, ie get `etc.Parent.FullName` to show `SysWOW64`?

Comment: @IlyaKozhevnikov - I'm not immediately aware of a way to do so. Looking in the obvious places (i.e. alongside the other functions mentioned in the linked article), I'm not seeing any likely native functions, let alone anything useful from .NET

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... It could be a permissions issue ( read permission maybe ), but you would probably get an error if that was the case.

See if it shows up using the `Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Windows\System32\drivers")` method on .

Here is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx).